# How to extract the return value from THEN in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I want to return one single user from two different user collections inside Stream function. Now, I need to extract the value comes from .then((value) => ... ), so I can return it.
In the code below, always return null because I can not use the value inside then outside then.

```
  Stream? getCurrentUser(String uid) {
    final adminRef = firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.admins).doc(uid).get();
    adminRef.then((value){
      if(value.exists){
        final adminsCollection = firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.admins).where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).limit(1);
        return adminsCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => AdminrModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList().first);
      }else if (!value.exists){
        final usersCollection = firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.users).where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).limit(1);
        return usersCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList().first);
      }
    });
    return null;
  }
```

I tried to use async/await but it doesn’t work with Streams.

Comment: Make your method `async*`. You can then use await and `yield*` - see https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams Of course, you will need to think of an alternative to returning null - perhaps an empty stream (i.e. just return from the method without yielding anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solve the problem by using async* and yield* @Richard Heap

```
Stream? getCurrentUser(String uid) async* {
    final adminRef = await firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.admins).doc(uid).get();
    if(adminRef.exists){
          final adminsCollection = firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.admins).where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).limit(1);
          yield* adminsCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => AdminModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList().first);
    }
        final usersCollection = firebaseFirestore!.collection(FirebaseConst.users).where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).limit(1);
        yield* usersCollection.snapshots().map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList().first);
}
```